# crystal report only show one row of datatable

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I create a report with crystal report in my c# project. that have 5 pages. i add this pages in detail section. I want to show a table that bound from data table at the end of the last page(page 5).
but my datatable in report show only first row of my datatable

Comment: how you are calling datatable and set it in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add first pages in report header section. and important things was that I didn 't use group name field. when i use group name. my table show every rows of data table

Answer (score 0):

does the report work in design mode?
if so
and if you use more than one table in report **you may have linked the tables in the report**. unlink them when reporting in ADO.net